# Sendgrid generate personalized content while sending

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I need to send an email to my user list in Sendgrid. The emails should include a personalised link to my website. These links can't be pre-generated.

Can Sendgrid call a Cloud Function, or make an API call to generate the personalised links?

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some context to understand exactly what you're trying to do.
It sounds like you are using [SendGrid Contact Lists](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/managing-contacts/create-and-manage-contacts)/Segments, and you want to use a [single send](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/single-sends) to email them. Is that accurate?

Using Single Sends, you can use [handlebars templating](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars) to generate your emails, however, handlebars does not let you make HTTP requests or call Cloud Functions. You can pull data from the SendGrid Contact, so if you need to have a personalized link to your website, that URL will need to be composed of data in the SendGrid Contact.

If the data you need in the URL is not stored in the Contact yet, you can [update the contact and store the data in a custom field](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact), then pull the data from the contact in your Handlebars template.

---

If you aren't using SendGrid Contacts, but instead, you're pulling your contacts from somewhere using node.js, then you can use personalization with either [Substitution Tags](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/substitution-tags) or [Dynamic Email Templates](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates) in the SendGrid node.js library.